# unable to get right position of texBox in Thumb of seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

I am working in android. I am designing a seekbar. I added thumb there. It is showing at right place.

But at that thumb I want to show progress in text box. For this I am using this code:

```
int xPos = ((seekbar.getRight() - seekbar.getLeft()) * seekbar.getProgress()) /
            seekbar.getMax();
```

But this x coordinate is not exact. It is a little bit different.

Please suggest me what should I do for this.

Answer (score 1):

You've calculated the distance along the seekbar, so you just need to add seekbar.getLeft() onto it:

```
int xPos = (((seekbar.getRight() - seekbar.getLeft()) * seekbar.getProgress()) /
            seekbar.getMax()) + seekbar.getLeft();
```