# Textview over seekbar android

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I want to make a TextView over the seekbar and run into when I change value but not success. When i'm in value = 0, it's right but when i change value, it's wrong. THanks.
/////////////////////.................................

```
 float val = (progress * (seekBar.getWidth() - 2 * seekBar.getThumbOffset())) / seekBar.getMax();
        result.setX((float)seekBar.getX() + val + seekBar.getThumbOffset() /2-seekBar.getThumbOffset());

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResult"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_metter_note_retailer"
    android:text="0"  />
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sbBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_metter_retailer"
    android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"
    android:max="1500"
    android:progress="300"
    android:thumb="@drawable/bg_metter_retailer_tap"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/spacer" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="750" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="1500" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SeekBar - Showing progress with TextView above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946858/seekbar-showing-progress-with-textview-above)

Comment: It skil dont work smooth. The TextView and thumb of seekbar dont map together